How to persist the 0x240414 Bluetooth class in Ubuntu 24.04?
I added Class = 0x240414 in [General] in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf; I use Ubuntu 24.04.
I check that bluetooth service is running:
sudo systemctl status bluetooth

I check the used class (is not the one I configured):
sudo hciconfig -a | grep Class
Class: 0x7c0104

It's the same if I configure with 0x7C0414.
I manually set the class:
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x00240414
sudo hciconfig -a | grep Class
Class: 0x240414

Without 0x240414 class my LG webOS TV OLED55C22LB won't connect to my computer (because doesn't see it as a Loudspeaker?).
What should I do for the Bluetooth class to be persisted?
PS: in Ubuntu 23.10 the class 0x7c0104 (though not the one configured in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf) worked with LG webOS TV OLED55C22LB

Are you using Ubuntu 23.10?

no, Ubuntu 24.04 (as pointed out in the question)
